# User defined comparator for member of C++ class

Tags: c++, class, comparator

I have a quick question concerning the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct mySet{
    
    mySet(){
    }

    auto compare = [](int a, int b){ return a > b; };
    
    map<int, int, bool(*)(int, int)> myMap(compare);
    
    void insert(int x){
        if(myMap.find(x) == myMap.end()) myMap[x] = 1;
        else myMap[x]++;
    }
    
    void output(){
        for(auto p : myMap) cout << p.first << " " << p.second << endl;   
    }
};

int main()
{
  mySet thing;
  thing.insert(1);
  thing.insert(2);
  thing.insert(1);
  thing.output();
}
```

This code throws an error which I suspect revolves around the

```
    auto compare = [](int a, int b){ return a > b; };
    
    map<int, int, bool(*)(int, int)> myMap(compare);
```

My understanding is that this won't compile because compare is a member of a class which needs an instance in order to be called.

If I replace this code with

```
    static auto compare = [](int a, int b){ return a > b; };
```

it still won't compile because it needs at least one instance of mySet in order for compare to be called.

My questions are:

1. Is my understanding correct, or is there something more sinister going on that types of functions and the type of the comparator in std::map?
2. Is there a simple solution to declaring a member of a class with a user defined comparator? The simplest idea I have is to just declare the member as

```
std::map<int, int, bool(*)(int, int)> myMap;
```

then pass a function into the constructor like

```
mySet( bool(*f)(int, int) ){
     map<int, int, bool(*)(int, int)> newMap (f);
     myMap = newMap;
}
```

Just curious if there is a simpler solution and trying to understand what's going on a bit better.

Thanks and appreciation for any help.

Comment: `std::map<int, int, std::greater<int>>`?

Comment: Your `insert` method can be simplified to `myMap[x]++;`, `operator[]` inserts default value (0 in your case) when key is not present.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, I wanted a more complicated compare function, but simplified the code a bit so it's easier to read.

@Peter If I wrote ```bool(*compare)(int, int)```, will ```compare``` be cast as a ```bool(*)(int, int)```?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have non-static members declared with `auto`.

and in-class initialization of static non-constexpr data member of non-integral type is not possible neither.

In-class initialization doesn't use `()` but `{}` (or `=`) (to avoid issue with vexing parse)

So you might use:

```
static constexpr auto compare = [](int a, int b){ return a > b; };
    
std::map<int, int, bool(*)(int, int)> myMap{compare};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fede7ead7f9d4d32)

or in your case, simply:

```
std::map<int, int, std::greater<int>> myMap;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff6a8607cb090840)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Follow up question: I noticed that if I try to run the first demo at cpp.sh, it doesn't compile with an error that reads: ```error: 'constexpr const mySet::<lambda(int, int)> mySet::compare', declared using local type 'const mySet::<lambda(int, int)>', is used but never defined```. Is something compiler-dependent going on?

Comment: requires C++17 for several reasons.